# Box2D - Forces vs. Torques

Tags: javascript, box2d, physics, game-physics

I'm a little confused about how forces work in Box2D. I'm trying to implement a simple agent using Kripken's [Box2D.js](https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js), with some basic steering behavior. I'm trying to apply a steering force like the one Daniel Shiffman describes in [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/): `steering_force = desired_velocity - actual_velocity`. I'm having no trouble calculating that force, but I'm getting confused when I apply it (I apply it to a point in front of the body). The body moves in the direction I'd expect, but without rotating. Should I separately apply a torque?

Thanks! not much of a question I guess

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for example if you want to move in left or right direction, you should create two forces like below "l" and "r" and a separate steering force.
Here 5 represent amount of force.
below code will work with keyboard left and right arrow keys

```
PVector l = new PVector (-5, 0);
PVector r = new PVector (5, 0);
void keyPressed() {
  if (key==CODED) {
    if (keyCode==LEFT) {
      mover.applyForce(l);
      mover.update();
    }
    if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
      mover.applyForce(r);
      mover.update();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't atall answer the question... The implementation of applyForce() is basically what he is asking for....